# Cakephp display no. of posts made by each user

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to this so apologies for any silly mistakes. I would like to have, on the users index page, a column displaying how many posts each user has made. The column is there, but I'm trying to figure out how to have it automatically update whenever a user makes a post.

**users/index.ctp**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Users</th>
        <th>Account type</th>
        <th>Registered</th>
        <th>No. of posts</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['User']['role']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['User']['created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['User']['post_count']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The default 'post_count' in the users table in my database is 0.

So in my Posts controller, I want to add a part to the add() function where the post_count of the user making the post is incremented by 1. The add() function is in **PostsController.php**:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_username'] = $this->Auth->user('username');
        $this->Post->create();
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
    }
}
```

I tried adding the following lines:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_username'] = $this->Auth->user('username');
        $this->Post->create();
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your post has been saved.'));
        --> $postCount = $this->Auth->user('post_count');
        --> $postCount++;
        --> $user['post_count'] = $postcount;
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
    }
}
```

but they have had no effect.
Any help would be appreciated, even just telling me if I'm on the right track or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP has a built in function (CounterCache) for what you're trying to do: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, incrementing or decrimenting post count in the user table is wrong approach. The best way to solve this problem is define hasMany & belongsTo relationships in the User & Post models. Once the relationship is appropriate with foreign key. In the user index page you will get number of posts belongs to each user.

Note: To get number of posts created by user

Comment: Ah I see, so would I need to define both "User hasMany Posts" AND "Post belongsTo User" relationships? Or would a "Post belongsTo User" alone be enough?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has a similar question to me in the future, I solved this by using the counterCache function.

I wrote in the **Post** model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'counterCache' => true,
    )
);
```